# Remembering folds across sessions but in Lua

Tags: neovim, autocmd

the question is as the title says. I have code that works but not as I expect.

[image]

For example, I have a fold here. And another one as well.

[image]

These two folds are from the same file. When I save and quit then come back. Only the fold in the first image remains *closed*. While the fold in the second image still exists, but I have to go over to it and run `zc` to close it manually.

This is the code I borrowed from solutions here and modified.

```lua
local folds_augroup = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("Folds", { clear=true })
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("BufWritePost", {
    group = folds_augroup,
    command = "mkview | filetype detect | set foldmethod=manual"
})

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("QuitPre", {
    group = folds_augroup,
    command = "mkview | filetype detect | set foldmethod=manual"
})

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("BufWinEnter", {
    group = folds_augroup,
    command = "silent! loadview | filetype detect | set foldmethod=manual | silent! foldclose!"
})
```

The expected outcome is that

1. When I make folds they are remembered.
2. All folds remained closed even if I have them opened from a previous session.

Right now my code only does 1, not 2.

Comment: I strongly recommend against autocommands that make and restore views—one day, you’ll be confused by behavior from an automatically restored view. I’ve seen it dozens of times.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble what do you suggest then?

Comment: Using non-`manual` folds, typically, or creating and restoring views manually so that it's always and only when you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `zM` command:

```lua
local folds_augroup = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("Folds", { clear=true })
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("BufWritePost", {
    group = folds_augroup,
    command = "mkview | filetype detect | set foldmethod=manual"
})

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("QuitPre", {
    group = folds_augroup,
    command = "mkview | filetype detect | set foldmethod=manual"
})

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("BufWinEnter", {
    group = folds_augroup,
    command = "silent! loadview | filetype detect | set foldmethod=manual | normal! zM"
})
```

Comment: I tried the solution but it has the same effect. If there are two folds, only one remains closed when re-opening that file.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll investigate further :-/

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce your problem. The code provided seems to work fine on my machine. Maybe could you give us more precise information about how you reproduce the problem (a step by step approach: What you do, what you get and what you expect)?

Comment: Hmm, that's alright. I'll dig more into and see what I can get. Thanks :-)